# Using :extend() in LESS with pseudo-elements

Tags: css, less, pseudo-element

I would like to code a simple alert component that has color variations as well as font icon variations. The icons are coded with `:before`. I can write it fine in in vanilla CSS but I want to do it in LESS as compact as possible and I am stuck with using `:extend()` which I rarely used :(

```
.base-alert {
    color: red;
    ...
    &:before {
        content: 'base-icon-unicode';
        ...
    }
}
```

In vanilla CSS the code for the variation classes would be like:

```
.alert-warning {
    color: red;
}
.alert-warning:before {
    content "warning-icon-unicode";
}
```

But then the HTML should be `class="base-alert alert-warning"`. I would like to code the variation classes in LESS, using `:extend()` so in HTML I would only write `class="alert-warning"` or `class="alert-succes"` and so on. Something like:

```
.alert-warning {
    &:extend(.base-alert);
    color: orange;
    &:before {
       content "warning-icon-unicode";
    }
}
```

But it the :before doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the following:

```
.alert-warning:extend(.base-alert all) {
  color: orange;

  &:before {
    content: "warning-icon-unicode";
  }
}
```

This basically just extends `.alert-warning` from `.base-alert` using the [`all` keyword](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-). Then the `content` value for the pseudo-element is changed to `warning-icon-unicode` and the color is changed to orange.

---

Based on your comment about extending to multiple classes, I guess you could use the following, which will essentially just alias the selector:

```
.alert-warning, .alert-warning2 {
  &:extend(.base-alert all);

  color: orange;

  &:before {
    content: "warning-icon-unicode";
  }
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your preferences, you could also use the following, which will produce the same desired results.

```
.alert-warning:extend(.base-alert all),
.alert-warning2:extend(.base-alert all) {
  color: orange;

  &:before {
    content: "warning-icon-unicode";
  }
}
```

..this will work the same as well:

```
.alert-warning:extend(.base-alert all) {
  color: orange;

  &:before {
    content: "warning-icon-unicode";
  }
}

.alert-warning2:extend(.alert-warning all) {}
```

Comment: What if you want to extend on two classes like `.alert-warning, .alert-warning2 {...}` ?

Comment: @LavaRo Are you saying that you want `.alert-warning` and `.alert-warning2` to have the same styling?

Comment: Yes. `.alert-warning, .alert-warning2 { color: red;}` and `.alert-warning:before, .alert-warning2:before {content "warning-icon-unicode";}` I have some other classes somewhere that I would like to apply these styles to as well.

Comment: @LavaRo Updated.. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I got it. `.alert-warning:extend(.base-alert all), .alert-warning2:extend(.base-alert all) {......}` Unless there is other more 'proper' way. This seems to work though

Comment: There's less verbose way to extend for several classes: `.alert-warning, .alert-warning2 {&:extend(.base-alert all);}`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Nice, I didn't realize you could do that :) I initially tried `.alert-warning, .alert-warning2 {&:extend(.base-alert all) {...} }`. I didn't realize that you couldn't add CSS inside of `&:extend(.base-alert all);` Thanks for your comment!